# After importing package remains on database even after deletion

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a SQL Server newbie. I imported a package stored on my filesystem into my SQL Server 2008R2 database. Later on I deleted the package from the file system. However the package continues to remain in the SQL Server database and even executes!

What little I know implies this should not happen since even SQL Server will be referring to that package stored in the filesystem. So my question is: is this behaviour normal? If not what could be the possible reason for it

Cheerio

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server Agent / Jobs folder in Management Studio? There is probably a job that is scheduled and is referencing the package (or a copy of it).

Comment: This is absolutely normal! When you loaded the package into SQL Server, a complete copy of it was stored inside SQL Server - it's no longer dependent on the package on disk - it's now an object inside the SQL Server engine.

Comment: @Aaron> The only job running syspolicy_purge_history

Comment: So who is executing the package and how are you determining that it is being executed? Where exactly do you see evidence that the package still exists and is still being called?

Comment: @marc_s> Then why are there two folders namely FileSystem and MSDB. If everything gets stored in the DBMS itself why not club every package into a single folder?

Comment: @Aaron > The ghost package is located in (Integration Services Connection)>Stored Packages>  File System

Comment: I can actually execute/(run) the ghost package from here. As if it were on the filesystem

Comment: So why don't you delete the package by right-clicking it? As Marc explained, SSIS stores a copy in the engine, so you could delete the filesystem package, format the drive, set it on fire etc. and that won't delete the copy SQL Server had loaded.

Comment: @Aaron> Yes I can do that. But my query is if it is supposed to be stored on the filesystem and I delete it from the filesystem, shouldnt that affect the SQL SERVER Management Studio as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much pondering and asking some serious sql-savvy people I feel this behaviour it pretty much natural. The two folders have been created just to distinguish amongst the sources from where the packages were obtained. Once imported the package is saved in the database. Then it's location does not matter much. In my example, a copy of the package is created and stored in the database.
   Thank you all for your help and time :)

Answer (score 1):

When the package is on the file system, then it's sitting well where ever you want it. When the package is in the database, it will be stored in the msdb catalog in `dbo.sysssispackage` for 2008/2008R2 and 2012 if you are using the package deployment model. 2005 uses `dbo.sysdtspackages90` and 2012 in project deployment model will use the `SSISDB` catalog.

So now you know that it's in a table and that is what the agent is able to reference. If you wish to get rid of it, call the appropriate stored procedure. In this case, it's `msdb.dbo.sp_ssis_deletepackage` It takes 2 parameters, the name of the package and the folder the package is located in. The root folder is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. Otherwise, run the following query with the proper package name in there and it will generate the call you need to delete said package.

As always, evaluate the statement before blindly running it.

```
SELECT 
    P.name
,   P.folderid
,   'EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_ssis_deletepackage @name = ''' + P.name + ''', @folderid = ''' + CAST(P.folderid as varchar(50)) + '''' AS run_me
FROM 
    dbo.sysssispackages AS P
WHERE
    P.name = 'Package'
```

Comment: Yes I completely agree with your statement above. But as you said packages stored in the file system will have to be saved on the FIlesystem folder and those in DB will be saved in the MSDB folder. On my SQL SERVER management studio, the ghost package is being displayed on the Filesystem folder... Doesnt this imply that the package is saved in the Filesystem? However, it's not!! Thats my question, how come it is visible in filesystem and executes then?

Comment: Guys!! I have a request. If anyone can jus try this simple scenario on their systems and tell me about his/her results, it'd be great. Maybe this behaviour is supposed to happen, or there's something wrong with my SQL Server installation.
  All you have to do is place a package on the filesystem, Import this to your SQL server. Check if the package is present on the Filesystem folder. Then delete the package from the filesystem and re-check on the SQL server Filesystem Folder..

Thanks